# Shell: It is possible for a sourced script to echo string to the stdout [SH]

Tags: shell, sh, echo

Is it possible to print stuff while sourcing the `sh` (Not `bash`) script?

Example:

```
> echo script.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello World"
> ./script.sh
Hello World
> source ./script.sh
```

After running the last command, it doesn't print `Hello World` to the stdout. However, if I'll run `./script.sh` it will print.

Am I missing something? How can I solve this?

**EDIT:**
What if I have functions declaration in the script? something like this: `print_help()`. It fails with the following error: `Badly placed ()'s.`

Comment: I tested just now, but I run normally... it printed `Hello Worl` too using `source ./script.sh`. what's your operating system?

Comment: When you *invoke* a function, you don't include the parentheses.